# Where does the Addams' wealth come from?

Tags: the-addams-family

In the Addams Family movies, there is a large chamber full of gold, money and jewels. Where did the wealth come from? In the first [Addams Family](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101272/) movie, there is a comment made about it being Fester's money.

I recall seeing a few times in the old TV show, Gomez standing next to a ticker tape machine and looking at the quotes. This confuses me as to the origin of the wealth and whose it really is.

Comment: I always like to imagine that some of the wealth came from the treasure in the film 'Cutthroat Island' where members of the 'Adams Family' are attempting to kill each other off for ownership of the treasure. The very nature of the characters, especially Uncle Dawg, remind me a lot of the Addams.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to wiki and the "[Forbes Fictional 15](https://www.forbes.com/2007/12/11/gomez-addams-money-oped-books-cx_de_fict1507_1211addams.html)", Gomez Addams (originally penned in the comics with no surname, the name Gomez was chosen by John Astin, the actor portraying him for TV), the source is given as inheritance and investments.

The character is purported to be descended from Castilian royalty and British aristocracy, which would account for the inheritance portion, and the other comes from lucky (rather than sage) investments. One example given is a swamp that he bought for "scenic value" that turned out to have massive oil deposits, another is a mummified hand he bought at a flea market that turned out to be from an Egyptian pharaoh.

According to the Forbes article, his net worth is guessed at ~2 billion dollars US. It is to be noted, that due to Fester gaining control of the fortune, Gomez dropped off the fictional 15 list in 2008, and does not appear to have returned, despite having a presumed worth of more than some of the lower members of the list in the 1 billion USD range.